# upload file and validation form in ajax php

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form where I upload file I use ajax it works well, and I did the validation of the fields of this form and it works too my goal is to combine the two here is my code:

```
 $("form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
          var formData = new FormData(this);
          var name = $("#name").val();
          var email = $("#email").val();
          var file = $("#file").val();
          var submit = $("#submit").val();
          $.ajax({
              url: 'test.php',
              type: 'post',
              data: formData,
              success: function(data){
              alert(data)
              },
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false
          });

      });   
    });              
    $(".form_mess").load("test.php", {
              name : name,
              email : email,
              file : file,
              submit : submit
    });
```

and in test.php I get my data and success and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your second call into the first success function.

*Note: the code below uses `$.post()` instead of `$.ajax()`, but the result is the same.*

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const name = $('#name').val()
    const email= $('#email').val()
    const file = $('#file').val()
    const submit = $('#submit').val()

    $.post('test.php', {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        file: file,
        submit: submit
    }, function(data) {
        alert(data)

        $(".form_mess").load('test.php', {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            file: file,
            submit: submit
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: but concerning the file upload I have to use Dataform no, where to put it

Comment: Nevermind, then, I oversimplified. My anwser is still the same, put your `.load` code in the `function(data){}`.

Comment: if i change $ .ajax by $ .post the dataform does not work, can i keep $ .ajax and in success i add my load